# VB Linq GroupBy Min

Tags: vb.net, linq, min

I want only the minimum term per program and to return a new list of program selections using Linq (VB).

```
  Public Class ProgramSelection
    Public term As String
    Public program As String
  End Class

    Sub Main(args() As string)

        Dim ps As New List(Of ProgramSelection)
        ps.Add(New ProgramSelection With {.term = "202009", .program="2803"})
        ps.Add(New ProgramSelection With {.term = "202005", .program="9002"})
        ps.Add(New ProgramSelection With {.term = "202001", .program="2803"})
       
        Dim o = ps.GroupBy(Function(p) New With {Key p.program, p.term }).ToList()
        For Each g In o
            Console.WriteLine(g.Key.program & "---" & g.Key.ToString)
            Console.WriteLine()
        Next
     
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've got it right, you want a selection (a filter) of the existing `List(Of ProgramSelection)` where the `term` is the minimum value and return only the filtered elements in the list as a new `List(Of ProgramSelection)`.

You can `GroupBy()` as you're doing, then, for each Grouping, get the `Min()` value of the `term` property and build a new ProgramSelection element with the Grouping Key and the min value found. Something like this:

```
Dim o = ps.GroupBy(Function(p) p.program).
          Select(Function(gp) New ProgramSelection() With {
              .program = gp.Key, .term = gp.Min(Function(p) p.term)
          }).ToList()
```

Another method, using Select() to get the groupings and `OrderBy().First()` to filter the selection based on the minimum value of the term property, converted - in this case - to an Integer value (I'm not sure it's possible in the real class. In case you have all *numbers* there):

```
Dim o = ps.GroupBy(Function(p) p.program).
           Select(Function(gp) gp.OrderBy(Function(p) CInt(p.term)).First()).ToList()
```

IMO, the `term` property should be an Integer. Using a string *can work* anyway, but since you want the *minimum* value... If *minimum* means something different, add the specifics.

Comment: Can the same be done by with just a .Where clause, instead of returning a new ProgramSelection?

Comment: See the edit, maybe that's enough for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Group collection by program and "select" only minimum term.

```
Dim result = programs.GroupBy(Function(p) p.program).
    Select(Function(group) $"{group.Key}---{g.Min(Function(p) p.term)}")

For Each item in result
    Console.WriteLine(item)
Next
```

Based on values of `.term` property you probably need to convert them into correctly comparable type `DateTime` or `Integer` before finding minimum value.

```
Dim result = programs.GroupBy(Function(p) p.program).
    Select(Function(group)
      Return New ProgramSelection With
      {
        .program = group.Key,
        .term = group.Select(Function(p) Integer.Parse(p.term)).Min().ToString()
      }
    End Function)

For Each program in result
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.program}---{p.term}")
Next
```